# C# DataGridView doesn't update in Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

I've created a ComboBox in which are displayed all the names of the tables from my database. When I click a button, the current Table is showed in the DataGridView. I've succeded to create an Insert button to add new data in the current table, but it doesn'e update the info in my database... Here is the code:

```
private void insertBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NUC\MICROGARDE;Initial Catalog=SQL;Integrated Security=True");

         int i = 0;
  //     SqlDataAdapter sda;

        con.Open();

        for (i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        { 
            string query = "insert into " + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + " (@" + dataGridView1.Columns[i] + ") VALUES ('" + this.dataGridView1.Columns[i] + "');";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        }

        con.Close();
```

Comment: Iv'e not worked with GridViews and ADO.NET for a little while but don't you need to execute the command? (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();)

Comment: well... I got error when I try to do something like this: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                SqlDataReader myReader;

                myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: @francydarkcool- You don't need `ExecuteReader`, you need `ExecuteNonQuery` since your sql is `INSERT` statement which you need just execute it, not return any data or something.

Comment: I've tried to write cmd.ExecuteNonQuey(); . It gives me the following error: Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@DataGridViewTextBoxColumn".

Comment: @francydarkcool- add  "cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@Field, "value"));"

Comment: I've tried this:  cmd.CommandText = "insert into " + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + " (@" + dataGridView1.Columns[i] + ") VALUES ('" + this.dataGridView1.Columns[i] + "');";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + dataGridView1.Columns[i], dataGridView1.Columns[i]);   Still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Change your code and check

```
protected void insertBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        string query = "";
        string columnText = "";
        string valueText = "";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;

        for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            columnText = "";
            valueText = "";
            for (j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                if (j != 0)
                {
                    columnText += ",";
                    valueText += ",";
                }
                columnText += dataGridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[j].Text;
                valueText += "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text + "'";   
            }
            query += "insert into " + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + " (" + columnText + ") values (" + valueText + ")";
        }

        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }          

    }
```

Comment: I've tried what you said, even added a MessageBox to show the message "no" if it won't be able to execute the query( catch { MessageBox.show("no");}... It shows "no" ....

Comment: I have edited the code, can you please check if its ok

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to do this code, just binding the table values to gridview and then inserting the same data to the same table doesn't make any sense.

you can do simple coding. For ref:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/select-add-update-and-delete-data-in-a-Asp-Net-gridview-control/

Comment: I want to add new data in the table in C# and when I click a button, the table to be updated in the database. And I want ths to work with all that tables from the database(each table has different columns)

Comment: I've tried the code but I've got 3 errors: "The 'Response' does not exist in the current context", Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'HeaderRow' and no extension method 'HeaderRow' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?), Error 2 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' could be found

Comment: Sorry.. the code pasted was for web forms not windows form.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your missing two key constructs:

- 1, Add parameters
- 2, Execute query

Your code edited:

```
    private void insertBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NUC\MICROGARDE;Initial Catalog=SQL;Integrated Security=True");

        int i = 0;
        con.Open();
        for (i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        { 
            string query = "insert into " + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + " (@" + dataGridView1.Columns[i] + ") VALUES ('" + this.dataGridView1.Columns[i] + "');";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@Field, "value"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@Field, "value"));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
     }
```

Using parameters also deters SQL injection.

Comment: Again, I get this error: Must declare the scalar variable "@DataGridViewTextBoxColumn".

Comment: Can you please post the name of your fields and table. You first need to determine if the results your passing in are correct. Have you tried debugging(stepping through)?

Comment: I have many tables wih different names and different columns names. I get the current table name in comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() (for example, "Probe A") and the columns names in dataGridView1.Columns[i]

Comment: We need to make sure comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() is "Probe A or any relevant table" and same applies to the column. Can you confirm this?